# Is there a way to overload operator ! in Swift to avoid crash in production builds?

Tags: ios, swift, exception, swift2, swift3

Forced unwrapping causes your application crashes if there exists a nil. This is really cool during the development phase of your application. But this is a headache for your production build espescially if you were too lazy to do the if let nil check.

Has anyone tried any operator overloading/overriding that stops these crashes for production build?

Comment: use guard to unwrap your optionals

Comment: Well... what do you want instead of a crash? You cannot operate on `nil` in Swift. If you had a `nil` optional `Int`, what would you expect `optionalInt! + 3` to be? The whole point of force unwrapping is your app cannot recover from that optional being `nil`.

Comment: You should also take a look at the `??` nil coalescing operator

Comment: It is not about lazy you are or not. It is how you must do it in Swift. Unwrapping `nil` is totally your fault as a programmer.

Comment: If you are writing too much code you should probably change the way you are coding. Swift has many ways to easily deal with the optionals. Just remove all force unwrapping from your code.

Comment: @LeoDabus yes, have been using the coalescing operator. So for something like `optionalInt ?? 0 + 3` works. Also `var xlabel = view.viewWithTag(1) as? UILabel ?? UILabel()` . But can we do this universally. So that you have to write less code.

Comment: You can define a postfix operator that operates on optionals of (for example) `UILabel` type, which unwraps them if possible or returns a new `UILabel`. But don't, this is shit design.

Answer (score 7):

No, there was not, there is not, and there should never be.

The crash is **INTENTIONAL**. The implementers of the Swift language went out of their way, on purpose, to design the force unwrap operator (`!`) to crash.

This is **by design**.

When `nil` is encountered and not safely handled, there are two ways to proceed:

1. Allow the program to continue in an inconsistent state, and allow it to behave in an undefined, unforeseen manner.

**or**

2. Crash the program, preventing it from continuing in an inconsistent, undefined, unforeseen state. This will protect your file system, databases, web services, etc. from permanent damage.

Which of the two options do you think makes more sense?

Comment: Agreed, you shouldn't be able to move forward. Is there a way where you can handle this universally and show an exception instead of the application crashing.

Comment: Of course not. Read carefully 1st option again. Even if you show an alert or whatever. App will stay in **inconsistent state**. Which means that users will see more and more of these alerts and eventually may happen that all user can do is playing with alerts rather than using the app.

Comment: Not currently. But doing `do`/`catch` would be no better than just properly programming it with `if let` and `guard` in the first place

Comment: @Silmaril For the record, Java lets your catch `NullPointerException`, and C# lets you catch `NullReferenceException`. It's possible, but it's dumb.

Comment: @AMomchilov I know that. But we are talking about Swift. The example with alerts is not happening on Java etc. languages just because developer tries to recover from such inconsistent stat, but is theoretically possible.

Comment: @Silmaril My point is that it's not cut/dry enough to warrant saying "*Of course* not". There are ways to handle it, but it would require immediately exiting the scope of the occurrence to prevent other statements downstream from using that `nil` value. A `throw` does just this.

Comment: @AMomchilov ok. Agree. Anyway it is not possible in Swift (catching exceptions).

Comment: you can catch exceptions in swift.

Comment: @Silmaril You can catch exceptions, but force unwrapping nil doesn't throw an exception

Comment: @AMomchilov Too much filth man. Thanks anyways.  I found a solution, maybe. It's like creating White Walkers because of men. I can't stress enough how bad this is.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html

Comment: @AMomchilov It is **Error Handling**. Not **Exception Handling**. Feel the difference. You can't recover from exception in Swift.

Comment: @Silmaril Oh you're right. I didn't realize the difference

Comment: @Silmaril You are coming from Java background I suppose. In Java you differentiate between error and exception. But i don't think in this context the literature makes a difference.

Comment: @user2369146 Excerpt from Apple's docs: `Although Swift error handling resembles exception handling in Objective-C, it is entirely separate functionality. If an Objective-C method throws an exception during runtime, Swift triggers a runtime error. There is no way to recover from Objective-C exceptions directly in Swift. Any exception handling behavior must be implemented in Objective-C code used by Swift.` P.S. My background is a bit deeper: Pascal, Delphi, C, C++, Assembler, C# and also includes Java. But since 2011 I'm using mostly Objective-C and Swift (right after it was introduced).

Answer (score 2):

To be honest I'd gouge my eyes out if I had to maintain a codebase that used something like this if it was possible. Swift features an easy way to solve your problem that you're actively avoiding because of laziness (optionals). You could probably put a guard around those variables, but it requires the same amount of effort as using if let statements. My suggested solution is to stop being lazy and use the language properly. Go through your codebase and fix this, it will save you more hours in the long run.

Answer (score 2):

Can't overload ! since it's reserved, but we can use ❗️

```swift
protocol Bangable {
    init()
}

postfix operator ❗️
postfix func ❗️<T: Bangable>(value: T?) -> T {
    #if DEBUG
    value!
    #else
    value ?? T.init()
    #endif
}

extension String: Bangable {}
extension Int: Bangable {}

let bangable: Int? = 8
let cantBangOnDebug: Int? = nil
print(bangable❗️) // 8
print(cantBangOnDebug❗️) // Crashes on Debug!
```

Please don't actually use this in production. This is just give an idea on how it COULD be accomplished, not that it should